# Difference between clone object and normal object

Tags: php, oop, loops, object, clone

In PHP How it differs when I create cloned object in a variable and new object created using a variable with the same class

For example

```
 $a = new classA();

 $b = clone $a;

 $c = new classA();
```

What is the difference between `$b` and `$c` ?

Comment: Nothing. Assuming you don't have any global variables (that violate dependency injection). Such as, when classA is instantiated, a random number is assigned to one of its property values. If you clone it ($b), it will have the same random number property value as $a, but creating a new class again ($c), might not have that same random number as the others. And of course, all will have different addresses.

Comment: The scenario presented is not good enough to show the difference between cloning and instantiating a new object. A clone has fully copied properties of the original, **including references**.

Comment: I think that you have to define meaning of `difference` in object context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the following example

```
<?php

class classA {
    public $x=0;  
}


$a = new classA();
$a->x = 20;

echo $a->x."<br />";

$b = clone $a;

$a->x = 30;

echo $a->x."<br />";

echo $b->x."<br />"; // 20 because x was 20 before cloning $a to $b

$a->x = 50;

echo $a->x."<br />"; // changed to 50

echo $b->x."<br />"; // stil 20, $a 


$c = new classA();

echo $c->x;
```

Using cloning make, you have property `x` in object `$b` the same as in object `$a` because cloning simple copies object. And when creating new object, you will have new object and property value will be 0.

Cloning is simple copying object because by default for objects:

```
$a = $b;
```

PHP won't do copying (as for simple types) but will point to exact place in memory.

So for simple types you use:

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a;
```

if you want to make a copy, but for objects you need to use clone:

```
$a = new classA();
$a->x = 20;
$b = clone $a;
```

to have the same effect.

You should look in manual at [Object and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) and [Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to understand those things.